# -1 inform moderator flags remaining

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Errrr ....

[image]

A few minutes later ...

[image]

**Edit**
After Marc's update:

[image]

Comment: You an have a moderator inform *you* one time. Use it wisely, e.g. for a wakeup call before an important meeting.

Comment: You used one too many!  Give.  It.  Back.  (:

Comment: I think someone _stole_ my flags !

Comment: @Rebecca, despite repeated exposure to your... "special" brand of smilies, that particular comment makes me think you're frowning angrily every time I see it.

Comment: Looks like another asymptotic bug.  From 0 to -0.499999..99 this time.

Comment: related (though it may be a different issue): see the comment from ire_and_curses [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83084/my-super-awesome-flag-weight-dropped-what-gives/83086#83086). We've both been at `-6` for a while.

Comment: @yhw42 I guess it's the same issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't this because your available flags vary with your flag weight?

Perhaps it changed and now your total flags are less, but you already spent the equivalent for the old value for the day.

Of course this is speculation that'd need to be confirmed by a dev.

*Update*: I can confirm that the reverse is true -- I ran out of flags on SO and after my flag weight increased, I had more to use.

Comment: @Juan I am not checking out my flag weight constantly, so perhaps it is as you suggest.

Comment: That doesn't explain why he could still flag and go from -1 flag remaining to -2 flags.

Comment: @Chris, he doesn't say he flagged again, only that a few minutes passed... enough for a mod to dismiss some of his previous flags as invalid.

Comment: That's true - I did assume that he could flag. My bad.

Comment: I considered suggesting this, but I know it could not have been the answer around the time the Deputy badge was introduced, when I was rapidly growing my flag weight and hit the cap on several days. Of course, there's no predicting what happens for the rest of today, now that the OP has reached negative land.

Comment: @Chris In fact, as my flags was exhausted, I was not able to flag again. (But tried to :D)

Answer (score 4):

Closing as too localized; I expect this relates to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83084/my-super-awesome-flag-weight-dropped-what-gives

Yesterday, at around 6:30 UTC, the flag weight algorithm was tweaked, and existing flag-weights refactored. You might have had 740 before-had, and 620 afterwards. The number of available flags depends (in part) on your flag-weight, hence this will have reduced.

And if you'd already spent all the flags available, you could well have spent more than you now theoretically have.

This only impacts yesterday, so I'm not overly concerned... and the UI is, in many ways, entirely correct.

---

Sigh; ok, to make things simpler, I've changed things to just display 0 if you've gone -ve.

Comment: This can happen under normal conditions though, as I've experienced. Consume your flags, then get enough marked invalid such that your flag weight drops more than 20 and you get into negative flags remaining.

Comment: @marcog oh, sure; we could just report 0 if you really want...

Comment: @Marc It really doesn't bother me at all, was just commenting on "This only impacts yesterday".

Comment: @Marc Negative and imaginary (ie complex) numbers in several SO ratings could run for an April 1st. joke ... Just imagine -e^(i π) close votes in a question

Comment: I think it was not related to the alg tweak, but to a mix of good and bad flagging which at a certain time gave as a result that I've been spending more flags than those allowed by my _new_ flag weight.

Comment: @belisarius almost worth doing on maths.SE just to poke them

Comment: @belisarius of course, -e^(iπ) is neither negative nor complex...

Comment: @Marc Of course not. And you know, there are more pretty convoluted ways to display an integer :)