# No flags available on MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I have a flag weight of 130 and haven't used any today but my inform moderator tags shows "0":

[image: an image demonstrating the 0 flags remaining]

Noted in the meta chat [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/567659#567659) and discussed. Mods have the ability.

Comment: I'm 175 and the same problem. If I try to use it I get "you can only use 13 tags in one day" or something similar. (It disappears if you try to copy the text grrr)

Comment: I'll play the skeptic here and ponder [whether this is related to an earlier fix or not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83187/1-inform-moderator-flags-remaining).

Comment: I'm at 270, and same issue. The text was "You can only flag for moderator attention 26 times per day (click on this box to dismiss)." (I took a screenshot.)

Comment: @drachenstern just Screen shot it

Comment: @GraceNote I thought the same...

Comment: @Myles was it really that big a deal? We've all seen it once or twice (I would hope) :p

Comment: @Grace - well, what's the difference between Min(x,0) and Max(x,0), eh?

Comment: @Marc ~ That sounds an awful lot like a math question ... you better ask over there :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed by @MarcGravell all is working nicely now...